# How to change data format in sql?

Tags: sql, date, format, date-format

I'm trying to change the data format to the **"Aug 15, 2005"** type from "2005-08-15" in SQL. I've tried multiple different functions like DATE_FORMAT, FORMAT, CONVERT, etc. But it seems like nothing has worked.

```
SELECT FORMAT(release_date, 'MMM dd, yyyy') AS publish_date
FROM articles;
```

This doesn't return an error, however, it returns

| publish_date |
| --- |
| 2005-08-15 |

Column alias worked but the format hasn't changed.

It must be a simple thing but I can't figure it out. I will appreciate it if anyone can help me with this. This is my first time asking a question here, sorry if my question isn't clear. If so, please let me know! Thanks :)

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I'm using jupyter and I'm supposed to start sql code from "%%sql
postgresql:///articles" does this mean I'm using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'dddd, MMMM, yyyy') AS date
```

This should output as long day, long month, and long year.

Comment: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) function getdate() does not exist 

I tried this and this error showed up. Thank you though

Comment: Which SQL are you running?

Comment: I'm using jupyter and I'm supposed to start sql code from "%%sql postgresql:///articles" does this mean I'm using PostgreSQL?

Comment: So psycopg2 is a way of interacting with the db through python. To break down the problem, I would first go to the pgAdmin interface and run the query there in isolation and get the syntax down. You can then follow that up by pulling the syntax into the python code.

Comment: I would also direct you to the psycopg docs for syntax. https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html